# how to parse below json data to kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Hi guys i've been able to parse the name/practiceOnDate attributes into a kotlin data class
but i couldn't parse the exercices attribute correctly you can check the screenshot for the output that I'am getting. do you have any idea what I must do? (EDIT: I'am displaying data in a recyclerView)

```
[
{
    "name": "Introductory Session",
    "practicedOnDate": "2016-05-08T14:48:28.257Z",
    "exercises": [
        {
            "exerciseId": "0",
            "name": "Quarters flat minor C",
            "practicedAtBpm": 40
        },
        {
            "exerciseId": "1",
            "name": "Triplets flat major A",
            "practicedAtBpm": 40
        },
        {
            "exerciseId": "2",
            "name": "Eigths flat minor A",
            "practicedAtBpm": 40
        },
        {
            "exerciseId": "3",
            "name": "Eigths sharp minor C",
            "practicedAtBpm": 40
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my getSessions function:

```
private fun getSessions() {
    val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData()

    retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<SessionsItem>?> {
        override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<SessionsItem>?>,
                response: Response<List<SessionsItem>?>
        ) {
            val responseBody = response.body()!! //NOT NULL
            myAdapter = sessionAdapter(baseContext,responseBody)
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            recyclerview.adapter = myAdapter


        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<SessionsItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
            d("MainActivity","onFailure"+t.message)
        }
    })
}
```

SessionAdapter :

```
class sessionAdapter (val context:Context,val sessionList:List<SessionsItem>):RecyclerView.Adapter<sessionAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var sessionName:TextView
    var practicedOnDate:TextView
    var exercises:TextView

    init {
        sessionName = itemView.sessionName
        practicedOnDate = itemView.practicedOnDate
        exercises = itemView.exercices
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_items,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.sessionName.text = sessionList[position].name
    holder.practicedOnDate.text = sessionList[position].practicedOnDate
    println(sessionList[position].exercises.get(0))
    holder.exercises.text =sessionList[position].exercises.toString()
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return sessionList.size
}}
```

my session data class :

```
data class SessionsItem(
val exercises: List<Exercise>,
val name: String,
val practicedOnDate: String)
```

my exercice data class which i could not use:

```
data class Exercise(
val exerciseId: String,
val name: String,
val practicedAtBpm: Int)
```

this is my output:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgHtx.png)

I just want to get the name and practicedAtBpm attributes for the exercices but im getting everything

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your output. What are you getting that you don't want to get?

Comment: hi sir thank you for your quick response i just want to get the name and practicedAtBpm attributes from the list look at the screenshot to understand what im trying to do
EDIT: I'm getting this Exercise(exerciseId=0, name=Quarters flat minor C, practicedAtBpm=40)
and i want only to get :name=Quarters flat minor C, practicedAtBpm=40

Comment: So you don't want `exerciseId`? Then why did you define it in your Excercise class?

Comment: you're right sir i just removed it  this is my display right now : Exercise(name=Triplets sharp major A, practicedAtBpm=141) the only remaining problem is i dont want the class name to be displayed i just want both attributes  like this : 
name=Triplets sharp major A, practicedAtBpm=141

Comment: Then you need to override `toString()` and provide your own version of how to display it. Or you can manually put the String you want in your `onBindViewHolder()` instead of using `toString()`. And if you are doing that, you don't need to remove `exerciseId` from the properties if you don't want to lose that information.

Comment: thank you sir I overrided toString() method and everything is fine one more thing 
i don't understand why I still have these square brackets[] is there anyway to remove them here is an example if you did not understand me 
(this)[name : Quarters flat minor CpractictedAtBpm : 40
    , name : Triplets flat major ApractictedAtBpm : 40
    , name : Eigths flat minor ApractictedAtBpm : 40
    , name : Eigths sharp minor CpractictedAtBpm : 40
    ](this)

Comment: It's because you're calling `toString` on your `List<Exercise>`. The `toString()` of the backing class of the List puts brackets around the output. You can use `joinToString()` instead to get it without brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overwrite toString() in Exercise data class like below

```
data class Exercise(
val exerciseId: String,
val name: String,
val practicedAtBpm: Int){
override fun toString(): String = "name=$name, practicedAtBpm=$practicedAtBpm"
}
```

Comment: Hi sir thank you, your solution is working one more thing i don't understand why I still have these square brackets[] is there anyway to remove them here is an example if you did not understand me (this)[name : Quarters flat minor CpractictedAtBpm : 40 , name : Triplets flat major ApractictedAtBpm : 40 , name : Eigths flat minor ApractictedAtBpm : 40 , name : Eigths sharp minor CpractictedAtBpm : 40 ](this)

Comment: holder.exercises.text =sessionList[position].exercises.joinToString()